# domain of some function

Tags: calculus

I need domain the following functions.
Can you help me?
$f(x)= \tan x .\cot x$ and $g(x)= \sqrt {1-\sin^2 x}$ and $h(x)= \sqrt {(1- \sin^2 x)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- $f(x)= \tan x \cdot \cot x$ we need $\sin x\neq 0 \, \land \,\cos x \neq 0$
- $g(x)= \sqrt {1-\sin^2 x}$ we need $1-\sin^2 x\ge 0$
- $h(x)= \sqrt {(1-\sin^2 x)^2}$ we need $(1-\sin^2 x)^2\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

- We have $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$. We have $\cos(x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \{ \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and $\sin(x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \{ k\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Hence domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{ \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi , k\pi\mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{ \frac{k\pi}{2} \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.
- $h(x)$ is defined as long as $(1-\sin^2(x))^2 \geq 0$, which always holds. Hence domain of $h$ is $\mathbb{R}$.
- $g(x)$ is defined as long as $1-\sin^2(x) \geq 0$. We have for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that $\sin(x) \in [-1,1]$, hence $\sin^2(x) \in [0,1]$, hence $1-\sin^2(x) \in [0,1]$. We thus have that domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$.